# Help with ActiveRecord exception "Failed to lazily initialize a collection - no session"

Tags: lazy-loading, castle-activerecord

I am writing a web app using Castle ActiveRecord, and I keep getting this exception whenever I try to access a lazy loaded list of related objects.  Here is my code:

```
        using(new SessionScope())
        {
            foreach (var field in eventObj.RegistrationFields)
            {
                //Do something with the field here...
            }
        }
```

The RegistrationFields property looks like this:

```
    [HasMany(Inverse = true, Lazy = true)]
    public IList<EventRegistrationField> RegistrationFields { get; set; }
```

The exception happens when the "eventObj.RegistrationFields" is accessed for the foreach loop.  I also made sure to set the isweb="true" attribute in my activeRecord config settings.  Does anyone know why this would happen?  Here is my config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="main" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EventScheduler;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
</connectionStrings>
<activerecord isWeb="true">
  <config>
    <add key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
    <add key="hibernate.dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect"/>
    <add key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
    <add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string_name" value="main"/>
  </config>
</activerecord>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're getting confused about sessions. `RegistrationFields` is a lazy property of `eventObj`. It is the session that loaded `eventObj` that would be responsible for loading `RegistrationFields`. You're explicitly opening a new session by using `new SessionScope()`, which creates a new session to which `eventObj` is not bound; therefore there is no owning session for it to get the data from. Even if the originating session is still alive, calling `new SessionScope()` nests a new session and hides the old one where it can't be seen until `Dispose()` is called on the current scope. Objects will not automatically attach themselves to the current session. This is the expected NHibernate behaviour.

It looks like you're trying to do session-per-unit-of-work, which is fine, but then the loading of objects *and* the resolution of all those objects' lazy collections must happen within that unit of work.

You could try moving to session-per-request (see the Castle docs for how to make this happen) and dropping the SessionScope creation. This will keep your objects live for the duration of a page request (which is as far as any lazy collection should live in a Web app). You must be aware, though, that in this scenario any change you make to a persistent object will be written to the DB on session flush (in effect, you should treat a change to the state of a persistent object as a change to the underlying data as if they were the same operation - then you can't go wrong).

Answer (score 1):

When was eventObj loaded?  That needs to be in the session too.  Also, check out the [ActiveRecord integration](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/trunk/integration/ar.html) section of the docs: